# How to add back a removed widget by removeWidget() from a QStatusBar?

Tags: qt, qwidget, qstatusbar

I have read the [QStatusBar class Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstatusbar.html#removeWidget), and it is says that `removeWidget()`:

> does not delete the widget but hides it. To add the widget again, you must call both the addWidget() and show() functions.

As per the instructions, I wrote the code below:

```
ui->statusbar->addWidget(ui->label);
ui->statusbar->removeWidget(ui->label);
ui->statusbar->addWidget(ui->label);
ui->statusbar->show();
```

I added label widget using Qt Designer.

I was Expecting that label will be added to the `statusbar` but it was not.

How to do I add it back to `statusbar`?

Answer (score 1):

You should call

```
ui->label->show()
```

instead of:

```
ui->statusbar->show()
```

As follows:

```
ui->statusbar->addWidget(ui->label);
ui->statusbar->removeWidget(ui->label);
ui->statusbar->addWidget(ui->label);
ui->label->show();
```